# QoS for variable bandwidth connections

Tags: router, home-networking, bandwidth, tomato, qos

My DSL connection does not have a reliable max speed.  I've used [Tomato's QoS](http://www.wi-fiplanet.com/tutorials/article.php/3800416/How-to-Manage-Traffic-Using-Tomato-and-QoS.htm) in the past, and it seems to work, but chokes when the DSL speed decreases lower than the max setting.

> If your upload speed varies by much, you will need to be conservative and use 90% of your **lowest score**.

But this doesn't mean "reserve a certain amount of bandwidth for high priority apps".  It actually *limits* the total bandwidth of the router to whatever I put in the box.  If I put a number that's higher than the actual bandwidth for that day, it can't do its job.  If I put a number that's too low, it limits everything to lower than what the modem's actually capable of:

For instance, normal speedtest.net results with QoS disabled:

- 2900 kbit/s down 700 kbit/s up
- 3140 kbit/s down 723 kbit/s up

After enabling QoS at 500 kbit/s down 100 kbit/s up to prove that it's limiting everything:

- 64 kbit/s down 459 kbit/s up
- 65 kbit/s down 456 kbit/s up

I really don't want to limit my bandwidth to 50% of the max speed all the time just to make QoS work, but I do want to be able to get priority for SSH stuff and web stuff, and decrease priority for background high-bandwidth stuff.  Is there a way to do this?  Like when high priority packets are going out, temporarily slow transmission of low priority packets?

Comment: Hah. I was just about to ask this question again.